# How to get rid of Lit "<!--?lit$" comments in html?

Tags: javascript, lit

I updated [Lit](https://lit.dev/) to `2.7.5`.
Now I have such comments everywhere in html:

```
<!--?lit$534310711$-->
```

How can I get rid of those comments?

P.S. It not a super big deal, but does matters. It makes e2e a bit harder, you have to write your selectors better than just "select first html node". I wonder, because in the previous version there were no such comments.

Comment: It's using these to keep track of state.  Why does it matter?

Comment: @Brad It makes e2e a bit harder, you have to write your selectors better than just "select first html node". I wonder, because in the previous version there were no such comments

Comment: That's a good thing - targeting nodes by their position is a code smell as it's extremely brittle. One small inconsequential change in the markup (as in this case, adding a comment) and your logic is broken. Use actual targeted selectors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well, I'm not the one who do the e2e, just have a request from my team. They definitely have to rewrite some code than.
So as I understand you, that's not possible to get rid of the comment blocks, right?

Comment: @eXception I don't know what you mean by "e2e", but yeah selecting elements by position sounds like a nightmare, and very brittle as Rory pointed out.

Comment: https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/748

Comment: @Brad Thanks. Make an answer of your comments and I'll accept it

Comment: @Brad "E2E" means "end to end testing". Basically automating a browser to click on elements as a human would to test stuff.